# document field returns null when querying groups of Prismic Content-Realtionship fields in graphql

Tags: graphql, gatsby, prismic.io

**Issue:**

I am using Prismic to send data through to my website.

In Prismic I have a Type (`testimonial_list`) that consists of a group of content-relation fields (Prismic Type `testimonials`).

To query the data on the inner Types I need to access them via the document field in graphql and use inline-fragments.

I have followed as instructed here:
https://github.com/angeloashmore/gatsby-source-prismic#Query-Content-Relation-fields

Inside graphql I have managed to navigate to the `testimonial` data-fields (on the `document` field) but the `document` field returns null, this is where I'm stuck. I can't work out why it would return null as the content exists and the fields are clearly being found in graphql.

**Info:**

My project is built using Gatsby and I'm using the plugin `gatsby-source-prismic` v3.1.1

Here you can see I can access the correct field data and I am getting the right number of nodes returned but `document` is empty:

[image]

This is the JSON for the `testimonial_list` Type on Prismic:

```
{
  "Main" : {
    "prismic_title" : {
      "type" : "StructuredText",
      "config" : {
        "single" : "heading6",
        "label" : "Title (only used to name entry in Prismic list)",
        "placeholder" : "Prismic list title (otherwise \"undefined\")"
      }
    },
    "page" : {
      "type" : "Select",
      "config" : {
        "options" : [ "Homepage", "Option 2", "Option 3" ],
        "label" : "Website page to appear on:"
      }
    },
    "testimonial_list" : {
      "type" : "Group",
      "config" : {
        "fields" : {
          "testimonial" : {
            "type" : "Link",
            "config" : {
              "select" : "document",
              "customtypes" : [ "testimonial" ],
              "label" : "testimonial"
            }
          }
        },
        "label" : "Testimonial List"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you for any help, if there is any more info I can supply to help deduce the issue please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, the issue turned out to be a typo in my gatsby-config where I was requiring the schema.

It was a daft mistake but stare at something too long and these things happen I guess.

In case anybody else has a similar issue you must ensure the property names of your Prismic schemas inside your gatsby-config are exactly the same as in Prismic.

For example if your Type in Prismic is called "my_type" then you must use that exact syntax - so for example don't use "myType".

Answer (score 0):

Hey it might be something related to the gatsby-source-prismic plugin
I would directly open an issue for it here if I were you: https://github.com/angeloashmore/gatsby-source-prismic/issues

Comment: It's looking that way, after speaking with the Prismic devs I think we're going to have to dive a little deeper :) ty